# Spark Structured Streaming stream-stream join question

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Scenario is slightly different than the classic stream-stream join

**streamA**: stream of transactions: transTS, userid, productid,...

**streamB**: stream of new products created: productid, productname, createTS, ...)

I want to join transactions with productIds, but I can't find a combination of watermarks/join conditions to make that happen.

```scala
streamA_wm = streamA.withWatermark("transTS", "3 minutes")
streamB_wm = streamB.withWatermark("createTS", "1 day")

streamA_wm
   .join(streamB_wm, "productId AND transTS >= createTS", "leftOuter")
```

The result is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Curious as to why the Products would be a Stream.

Comment: Because new products are created continuously, and I need some attributes of products in the join with the transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you *may* have the wrong approach here. Whilst products are transactional when created and updated, they are metadata relative the other Transaction Stream.

I would suggest the following:

1. Join the Transactions Stream to the reference data Products - which is not subjected to Stream processing.
2. Do not cache the Products, this ensures you go to source.
3. Use parquet, KUDU for the Products.

But may be there is a reason for a Stream for Products, but ... What happens if no more updates to Product made and you get data for that Product again via the Stream for Transactions?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I agree with you that Products are a dimension.. .however, they get created continuously and I need some of their attribute in the join with transactions.
So I was trying to consider them a "stream" just to make it work.

To go back to your suggestion... I can join with Products as reference data, but then I would lose attributes in Transactions that refer to Products created *after* I loaded the Products the first time...
Does it make sense?

Comment: I am sure now if you follow my suggestion it will be fine. Moreover, you will muss dara as I state.

Comment: I will try your approach. 
You are basically suggesting to "stream" Products into a fast cache (KUDU or Redis maybe, which is already there). And for each Transaction, access the cache and decode the ID.

And, to reply to your earlier comment, Products will keep coming at a rate of 1 every few seconds, and on their own stream.
"Products" and "Transactions" are obviously fake names and come from 2 different parts of the company, hence will stay in 2 different streams.

Comment: My point is that the productschap are not to be streamed or if they are you neef to persist for reuse for other transactions

Comment: "What if an old product is to be joined?"
That's why I would like to advocate Spark itself to support a Stream-Stream* join with the second stream being a growing dimension. 
That would take out the external cache alltogether.
Anyway.. thanks for your help!